# Can't start react native project with npm start

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm-start, expo

First i started with installing npm (version ) then expo cli (version ) then i initialise a project normaly then when i start my project with npm start and also expo start a get this message :

```
Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
ConfigError: Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
at Object.getExpoSDKVersion (C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Project.ts:22:9)
at ensureConfigHasDefaultValues (C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:419:22)
at fillAndReturnConfig (C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:101:10)
at getConfig (C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:137:10)
at configureProjectAsync (C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:288:25)
at action (C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:164:34)
at C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:341:16
at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:82:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BILAL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-17T00_34_22_028Z-debug.log

also i worked with react native and react-cli before for a simple app and it worked but this time i tried for a week without result

thank you so much

Comment: Did you install expo before start? => "npm install expo"

Comment: sorry  node v : 12.16.3   and npm v : 6.14.4

Comment: Please, install expo module, type this on terminal: npm install expo

Comment: @MayconMesquita  yes i did and a get this message :

Comment: npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path G:\APP\congres\node_modules\.staging\@babel\parser-c75ab002\LICENSE
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'G:\APP\congres\node_modules\.staging\@babel\parser-c75ab002\LICENSE'

Comment: this is my package.json : {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}

Comment: That error generally means that a file is being accessed by two different things at 'around' the same time. And 90% of those times it is because of an anti-virus or similar. 
> Do a "ctrl + Alt + Delete",
> Task Manager,
> Find all running instances of node server and kill them.
> Then, try Install the expo package again.

Comment: This github issue can help you, with this last error: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2464

Comment: sorry no anti virus  even i stoped windows defender to check , thank you @MayconMesquita for your time

Comment: I had the same issue in windows and it appeared when i moved my project from C: to D: (or the other way round). Maybe this could help you. Just move the project back to the other partition.

Comment: @mleister same thing. thank you guys

Comment: i posted an answer maybe you can accept it (and/or vote it up) to help other people :)